# How do you sort the answers to a question by number of votes per answer?

Tags: support, answers, voting, sorting

It seems like answers are normally sorted by number of votes, but I just found a question on StackOverflow that doesn't seem to be: [What is the single most influential book every programmer should read?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-programmer-should-read)

Is there a way to ask StackOverflow to sort these answers by vote?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the sorting tabs that are in the top right of the answer list. It will use your last setting, so maybe you clicked a link that had a different sort order.

[image: Tabs]

Comment: Note that the accepted answer will always be at the top regardless of the chosen sort option.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to sort by "number of votes" however, there is a way to sort by "net votes" (upvotes minus downvotes) which is the "votes" tab at the top of the answers list.