# Moving answers with more votes to the top of the list

Tags: feature-request, answers, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you sort the answers to a question by number of votes per answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81058/how-do-you-sort-the-answers-to-a-question-by-number-of-votes-per-answer)

I have seen that answers with many upvotes still remain at the bottom of the answers list. It is of particular importance,  when many answers are there and also because such answers are most times better ones, well researched and probably better ones.

That said, the selected answer deserves the topmost position, but it only seems logical to promote answers with more upvotes to the top of the answers list, probably below the selected answer, but based on descending order of the upvotes.

Comment: That already happens depending on your sorting view....

Comment: Did you just change the ordering of the answers? You're aware that these can be ordered by votes, creation date and last change?

Comment: @UnicornifiedBobby, Thanks for that. I hadn't used it till date. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- When answers are sorted by votes, the highest voted answer will appear directly below the accepted answer (if there is one).
- Ordering by "active" will sort the answers by how active they are - last edited / last posted, etc...
- Ordering by "oldest" simply places them in chronological order.

Comment: Ok thanks man.. That was it. I noticed it now only.

Comment: No problem!  Remember that the accepted answer is decided **only** by the OP so it should be taken with a pinch of salt...  It's only his/her opinion.  You should always glance down at the highest community voted answer as well...

Comment: Ya I do that always. But to a beginner of Stackoverflow, it might not be that obvious. :)

Comment: That's why we have the [faq] and meta :)  To help people understand how to use the site.